# SSIS: Source to Destination (Multiple Sources)

Tags: ssis

I have a SSIS Package that extract from Source database to destination SQL Server table.

I would like to add a second destination of the same data to export into a excel file. Is this possible or do I need to create a second process for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a Multicast component in the dataflow. If you need to send only some of the records, use a Conditional Split to filter.

[image]

Comment: THanks @billinkc.